# Android Studio Mac version v.0.3.2 is damaged

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to install Android Studio 0.3.2 but every time I end up with this error message:
Android Studio.app is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the trash

Can I download older version from somewhere, seems the app uploaded isn't working properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's colliding with the system security feature that requires all apps to be signed (and preferably only distributed through the Apple app store). You can go to Settings > Security & Privacy > General tab and choose "Anywhere" from "Allow apps downloaded from". You can change this temporarily while you launch Android Studio the first time, and then change it back. You can also usually right-click on the Android Studio icon and choose "Open" from the menu; it will give you a different warning with the option to proceed with launching it.

Comment: Thanks it works but i only noticed this since Maverick.. Before that the error message was different..

Comment: I came across the same thing in Mavericks. I had to go to the control panel and disable the setting, whereas before I was able to do it with a right-click on the app icon.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Settings > Security & Privacy > General tab and choose **"Anywhere"**.

In case if **"Anywhere"** option is missing from Settings > Security & Privacy > General Tab,

Open Terminal and run,

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Then close and reopen Settings > Security & Privacy > General Tab. It will be available that time.

After you finished you make it hidden for security purpose by,

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution if you're trying to install onto a USB:

1. Open(cmd + space) disk utility.
2. Click on your USB.
3. Click "Erase".

   1. In my case, I have decided to transform it into a Mac OS Extended.
4. Wait until the operation finishes successfully.

Install Android Studio onto your newly clean drive.
And I recommend you to download it in a folder(like "Applications") that you created, not just directly in /Volumes//..